# WPF MVVM Unit Tests for the ViewModel?

Tags: wpf, unit-testing, mvvm, viewmodel

I keep reading about the benefits of using MVVM, especially for unit testing. So, now I need to write unit tests for my ViewModel. Does anyone have any examples of this? Should I just generate the unit tests using VS2008 and select those tests that appear important?